# Injecting route configuration from module to module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I'm studying routing in angular and something is going wrong
I have the following file structure:

**index.html**

```
<br>script.js
<br>first/first.js (controller) second.html (view)
<br>second/second.js (controller) second.html (view)
```

**index.html**

```js
'use strict';

// script.js
angular.module('RoutingApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'RoutingApp.first',
  'RoutingApp.second',
  'RoutingApp.third',
])
.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/first'});
}]);

//first.js
'use strict';

angular.module('RoutingApp.first', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/first', {
    templateUrl: 'first/first.html',
    controller: 'First'
  });
}])

.controller('First', [function() {

}]);

//second.js
'use strict';

angular.module('RoutingApp.second', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/second', {
    templateUrl: 'second/second.html',
    controller: 'second'
  });
}])

.controller('second', [function() {

}]);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="RoutingApp">
 <head>
  <title>Routing app</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
     <li class="nav-item"><a href="#!first/first">Home</a></li>
     <li class="nav-item"><a href="#!second/second">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
  <div ng-view></div>
  //...
 </body>
</html>
```

and nothing happens.

What's wrong?

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "something is going wrong" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: **Divide and conquer.** When you have a small amount of code, but the source of the problem is entirely unclear, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back.

Comment: I researched a bit but can't find a definite answer .. it seems that you can't inject the configurations from a module into the other .. that means you probably have to define the routing configuration only in the module used in the ng-app directive ('RoutingApp') .. also if this is your question please change your question title to something like "injecting route configuration from module to module"

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma at

```
'RoutingApp.third',
```

That third route probably shouldn't be there either since it's not defined anywhere.

Comment: Did this help you?